# Numpy ndarray shape parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I've a 3 dimensional numpy array. When I try to print it's shape, I get (4, 1, 2). Now I'm struggling to figure out which value corresponds to `row`, `column` and `depth`.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

zone = np.array([[[221,529]],
               [[156,850]],
               [[374,858]],
               [[452,537]]])

print(zone.shape)
```

Comment: "row, column and depth" are *not concepts that apply*. Those are arbitrary designations that *you* give the array. The array just knows it has dimension (axis) 0, 1, and 2. You can think of them any way you'd like

Comment: What do you intend by the nesting of lists in the array creation?  Does `print(zone)` look the same?

Answer (score 0):

`.shape` returns dimensions respectively. So it means you have 4 rows, 1 column, and depth of 2.

Comment: are you sure with a given example?